# Disable imageIcon from accepting drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, imageicon

I have created various imageIcons on a JPanel and can drag and drop them onto each other. But I want to disable the ability of some of them from accepting drag and drop. IE I don't want some of them to be changed  .They have been set up using JLabel label = new Jlabel(icon) etc
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I worked it out. I reset the TransferHandler with a null poperty : mylabel.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(null));